# AngularJS application links/routes in anchor tag with HTML5 mode

Tags: angularjs

How do I link to other AngularJS application locations within an anchor `A` tag? I am using HTML5 hashless mode and would like to avoid having the page actually reload.

For example, in non-HTML5 mode I would do this:

```html
<a href='#/path'>Link</a>
```

In HTML5 mode I can do this:

```html
<a href='/path'>Link</a>
```

But this actually causes the browser to reload the new URL. I've also tried using `ng-href` and also the `/#/path` syntax but none of them seem to work as I'd like.

How do I properly link from an anchor tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**:

It seems like this is possible without using $location, you just have to keep the same base link. [From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> When you use HTML5 history API mode, you will need different links in different browsers, but all you have to do is specify regular URL links, such as: <a href="/some?foo=bar">link</a>
>
> When a user clicks on this link,
>
> - In a legacy browser, the URL changes to /index.html#!/some?foo=bar
> - In a modern browser, the URL changes to /some?foo=bar
>
> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain target element. Example: <a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain. Example: <a href="http://angularjs.org/"></a>
> - Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined. Example: <a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>

Old:

You should use the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). Inject it into the controller and put it on the $scope (or in a convenience method):

```js
function MainCtrl($scope,$location){
  $scope.goto = function(path){
    $location.path(path);
  }
}
```

```html
<a ng-click="goto('/path')">Link</a>
```

Comment: This is what I've done now in a controller on the body element. It just seems a little odd that there is no standard way of doing this.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test that out yet. But I trust that'll it work so I'll accept now.

Comment: I prefer to create portable apps. Can I use href and/or ng-href without prior knowledge of base path and html5mode on/off? Or should I always use ng-click in such case?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in html5mode enabled.

```
<a ng-href='./path'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular Js uses hash prefix followed by exclaimation. Hence if you want to use the anchor tag then have it this way.

Link

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09